# Is the total number of these figures a quartic polynomial with respect to $n$ ？

Tags: combinatorics, quadrilateral

My idea about this problem comes from my sister's high school math problem, how many quadrilaterals are there in the graph.

> [image]

This problem requires patience. You need to find squares, general parallelograms and trapezoids respectively. Finally, it comes to $3108$, or you can find out that the general term is $ n(n+1)(7n^2 - n-3)/6$.

*(Let the side length of the smallest square be $1$, and $n$ be the side length of the largest square)*.

Further exploration, when we find the number of parallelograms or triangles in the graph, we can finally get a quartic polynomial about $n$.

In other problems, such as how many parallelograms or triangles are there in the graph, we can still obtain a quartic polynomial about $n$.
[image]

These are other pictures, in which the number of triangles, parallelograms, squares, rectangles and quadrilaterals also seems to be about the quartic polynomial of $n$.
[image]

**So for the number of rectangles or squares or triangles or parallelograms or quadrilaterals in the regular pattern composed of triangles on these planes, I guess the answer is generally a quartic polynomial with a constant term of $0$ about $n$. We only need to find the first few terms, and then Lagrange interpolation can find the general term. Am I right?**

*My mother tongue is not English, so I use translation software, so there may be some deviation. As a newcomer to MSE, if my post violates the rules, I will delete it*

Comment: +1 for the question, but plugging 7 into that polynomial does not give 3108 (unless I'm not understanding something)

Comment: @QC_QAOA Sorry sir,it is n(n+1)(7n2−n−3)/6.... I forget the number 6.

Comment: +1 for the cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are counting rectangles in a grid then there are four degrees of freedom - length, width, and x, y coordinates. There are four pieces of data that you need to fully specify a rectangle in the grid. When you are counting all of them you are doing a quadruple sum, leading to a quartic. Same with parallelograms.

If you are just counting squares, or equilateral triangles, then you have only three degrees of freedom - size, x, y - so you get a cubic.

The zero constant term comes from the fact that the n=0 grid consisting of just one point contains no shapes.